# How to fix the keyNotFound(code: "BCLM") error?

Tags: macos, mac, 64-bit, battery-life, macbook-air

When using the `bclm` command[1] to change the max charge setting for my M2 Mac's battery. I am suddenly getting the error:

```
❯ sudo bclm write 90
keyNotFound(code: "BCLM")
```

`bclm` is installed with Homebrew and up to date.

```
❯ which bclm
/opt/homebrew/bin/bclm
❯ bclm --version
0.1.0
```

What does this mean? How do I fix it?

[1] https://github.com/zackelia/bclm

Answer (score 1):

The shell you're using must be running in arm architecture. (i.e., it can't be using rosetta.)

You can check by running `arch`.

This will not work with `bclm`:

```
❯ arch
i386
```

This will work:

```
❯ arch
arm64
```

My specific problem was I had accidentally set my `zsh` to `/usr/local/bin/zsh` which automatically uses rosetta to run in `i386` architecture. I needed to switch it back to `/bin/zsh` and then all worked fine.